# How to display coins only with coin symbol of a Currency and display it localized?

Tags: c#, currency, globalization

I want to display 1 coin, and display it correctly localized with the right coin symbol.

I Have this code :

```
Decimal myDecimal = new Decimal(0.01);

// Use the CurrentCulture French in France.
result = myDecimal.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
Console.WriteLine (result);

// Use the CurrentCulture Canadian
result = myDecimal.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("fr-CA"));
Console.WriteLine (result);

// Use the CurrentCulture USA
result = myDecimal.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
Console.WriteLine (result);
```

That gives me this result :

```
0,01 €
0,01 $
$0.01
```

I would like to have this result instead (or the right way to display cents in Canadian, USA and euro) :

```
1c
1¢
1¢
```

I searched a lot about currency to try to find how to display it. Microsoft doesn't give a basic way to convert it. I then found this article about cents on Wikipedia : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(monnaie). I'm starting to think that maybe cents is always 'c' or '¢' whatever country you are.

Is there a way to display cents in a localized way ?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think there is any currency formatter built into .net that will do this for you out of the box. You will have to create your own formatter and figure out how to track the correct symbol for cents based on the culture. Perhaps there is already a library that can do this for you (I would search NuGet). Alternatively you can push back on the requirement and ask to use the standard currency formatting like you already have.

Comment: AFAIK currency is usually formatted in the actual currency. For example: USA `$` (dollar), UK `£` (pound), China `¥` (renminbi ) etc... You'd have to create your own formatter to accomplish this.

Comment: I believe cents are always displayed as a fraction of dollars. The first way you were doing it is "correct" (even though it's not what you want).